# Consider a non-dividend paying stock subject to risk-free force of interest

Tags: finance

Consider a non-dividend paying stock subject to risk-free force of interest, r = 0.045 as well as volatility, σ = 0.24 and time horizon three months, i.e., T = 1/4 for a stock with current price S0 = $45. Recall that
dSt = St(rdt + σdBt) where {Bt}t≥0 is standard Brownian motion. 
Furthermore, recall that Brownian motion is Gaussian with mean 0 and variance t. That is, Bt ∼ N (0, t) for each t fixed, 0 ≤ t ≤ T. It follows that we can exploit this normality, thus leading to the discretisation
Sti − Sti−1 = Sti−1(r∆t + σ√∆t) for ∆t = ti − ti−1 where we assume that  is a random draw from standard Gaussian distribution, i.e.
 ∼ N (0, 1) (4)

Given our time horizon of 3 months, we would like to simulate prices for ∆t = 0.005, we simulate iteratively. In other words, after the first time period, we get
that
St1 − S0 = S0(r∆t + σ√
∆t)

Where we repeat until the final time step, T = 0.25.

Your task is to simulate 100 such sample paths.

Attempt at Question:

So I understand that we must use the formula St1 − S0 = S0(r∆t + σ√
∆t) for ∆t=0.005 so i created an excel spreadsheet and subbed in the values and went up by 0.005. I have attached an image of my excel spreedsheet[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92x7z.png)t.

but I only got 50 samples instead of 100. Im a little confused with the random draw from the standard gaussian distribution as that is multiplied by the volatility in the formula. Does that alternate between 0 and 1 and i have to do it for both 0 and 1 to get two seperate data sets that will add up to 100.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You are asked to produce a time series of simulated prices at times from $T=0$ years to $T=0.25$ years at intervals of $\Delta T = 0.005$. So each time series will contain $51$ values (if we count the values at both ends).

You are then asked to repeat this $100$ times, so you get $100$ time series with $51$ values in each one.

A random variable that follows a standard Gaussian distribution $N(0,1)$ can take any real value, but the distribution of its values will have a mean of $0$ and a variance of $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i think i understand. So what I have already done is essentially 1 time series from 0.005 to 0.25 with the random variable being 1. I am now asked to do this another 99 times but changing the random variable to any number that is real? Is there a function on excel that will do this? Thanks again for your help

Comment: @JamesM In Excel the formula =NORM.S.INV(RAND()) will return a random number with a $N(0,1)$ distribution. Note that the random number will change each time you recalculate the spreadsheet, so you should copy and paste the *values* in  your time series if you want to refer to them later.

Comment: thanks mate this all makes sense, just one more quick question is there a function i can use on excel to generate 100 samples or as they change would i need to copy and paste these values 100 times to another spreedsheet.